# jquery selector get element with a class inside a div

Tags: jquery

I'm dealing with jquery selector.
I have a portion of html that (simplified) looks like

```
<div class="tile">            
      message
      <a href="#" class="ui-icon ui-icon-pencil">link1</a>
      <a href="#" class="ui-icon ui-icon-close">linkb</a>    
</div>
```

this div is repeated severl times in the page

and in the relative javascript I want to add the code to show or hide the 2 links when the user pass the mouse over the "tile" div.
I wrote something like

```
$(function () {
    $(".tile").bind("mouseover", function () {
        $("this .ui-icon").show();
    });
    $(".tile").bind("mouseout", function () {
        $("this .ui-icon").hide();
    });
});
```

but this doesn't work.
Anyone can help me here?

Comment: Check your classes: tile ≠ tileAgenzia.

Comment: All the answers have an incredibly common adjustment to your question.  I wonder if it will work!

Comment: @GG: thanks, it was just a typing error while semplifing the code for posting on SO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Several options:

#### Minimal fix

You've used "this" within the selector; what you want to do is use `$(this)` to get a jQuery object for the actual tile the mouse moved over, and then use `find` to find the descendant elements. You're also better off using `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` than `mouseover` and `mouseout`:

```
$(function () {
    $(".tileAgenzia").bind("mouseenter", function () {
        $(this).find(".ui-icon").show();
    });
    $(".tileAgenzia").bind("mouseleave", function () {
        $(this).find(".ui-icon").hide();
    });
});
```

(The reason you're better off is that `mouseover` and `mouseout` *bubble*, and so as the mouse travels over descendant elements of the "tileAgenzia" elements, you'll see messages from those descendants.)

#### Use CSS (if you can)

But it's worth noting that unless you have to support IE6 and IE7 (and some people do), you can do this purely with CSS, no JavaScript required:

```
.tileAgenzia .ui-icon {
    display: none;
}
.tileAgenzia:hover .ui-icon {
    display: inline;
}
```

When the mouse is hovering anywhere over an element with the class "tileAgenzia", its descendant elements with the class "ui-icon" will be visible; when the mouse isn't hovering over it, they won't.

#### More concise jQuery

If you want to stick with the JavaScript solution, you can use the `hover` function, which is (if you pass it two functions) just a shortcut for hooking up `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`:

```
$(function () {
    $(".tileAgenzia").hover(
        // Called on mouseenter
        function () {
            $(this).find(".ui-icon").show();
        },
        // Called on mouseleave
        function () {
            $(this).find(".ui-icon").hide();
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: I like the CSS solution. Even if a lot of people here give me the most common solution, I'll vote your answer as accepted for the smart alternatives you give.

Comment: For the more concise answer, throw in my `$('.ui-icon', this)` and you have a winner! ;)

Comment: @John: More concise, true, I just hate to be that indirect. But I suppose those who like sausage shouldn't watch it being made (e.g., shouldn't look at the jQuery source). ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Try: `$( this ).find ( '.ui icon' ).show()`

Answer (score 2):

I think you may mean this:

```
$(this).find(".ui-icon")
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you wan to change:

```
$("this .ui-icon")
```

to

```
$(this).find(".ui-icon")
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to scope a jQuery select to the current subtree.  This is one using the `.find()` method.

```
$(function () {
    $(".tileAgenzia").bind("mouseover", function () {
        $(this).find(".ui-icon").show();
    });
    $(".tileAgenzia").bind("mouseout", function () {
        $(this).find(".ui-icon").hide();
    });
});
```

I might suggest this as a simpler alternative:

```
$(function () {
    $(".tileAgenzia").hover(function () {
        $(this).find(".ui-icon").toggle();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`this` in a string is not the same as the variable `this`.  Wrap it in jQuery and use `find`.

```
$(function () {
    $(".tileAgenzia").bind("mouseover", function () {
        $(this).find(".ui-icon").show();
    });
    $(".tileAgenzia").bind("mouseout", function () {
        $(this).find(".ui-icon").hide();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Ah, "this" shouldn't be inside the apostrophes. If you have jQuery loaded, I would do it the jQuery way:

```
$(".tile").hover(function(){
  $(this).children(".ui-icon").show();
}, function(){
  $(this).children(".ui-icon").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To limit your selector to a parent element, use either:

```
$(this).find(".ui-icon")
```

Or:

```
$('.ui-icon', this)
```

Comment: I'm surprised no-one else has suggested this second syntax. I use it all the time...

Comment: That's because jQuery internally runs it as `$(this).find` and personally, the syntax is a little awkward because `this` is on the wrong side of the selector.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
    $(".tileAgenzia").bind("mouseover", function () {
        $(this).find(".ui-icon").show();
    });
    $(".tileAgenzia").bind("mouseout", function () {
        $(this).find(".ui-icon").hide();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
    $(".tileAgenzia").bind("mouseover", function () {
        $(this).find(".ui-icon").show();
    });
    $(".tileAgenzia").bind("mouseout", function () {
         $(this).find(".ui-icon").show();
    });
});
```